# How to retrieve URL from link tags using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<article itemprop="articleBody">
  <p channel="wp.com" class="interstitial-link">
     <i>
        [<a href="www.URL.com" shape="rect">Link Text</a>]
     </i>
  </p>
<article>
```

How would I retrieve the URL and Link text with Jsoup from this HTML doc? 
I want it to look like this

"Link Text[URL]"

Edit: I want to retrieve only the links within

```
<article itemprop="articleBody"> ... <article>
```

Not the entire page. Also, I want all the links within, not just one.

Comment: Have you tried using selector https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am having trouble with. particulary with CSS selectors.

Comment: Can you post your attempts? Most of us visit Stack Overflow to help others correct their code rather than write it for them from scratch so by posting [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) you are increasing your chances of getting decent answer and explanation about problems you have made while creating your solution.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am new and trying to get better at posting questions. I will take your advice into consideration next-time.

Comment: In that case you should visit ["Stack Overflow question checklist"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) and ["how do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of our [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // connect to URL and retrieve source code as document
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    // find the link element in the article
    Element link = doc
            .select("article[itemprop=articleBody] p.interstitial-link i a")
            .first();

    // extract the link text
    String linkText = link.ownText();

    // extract the full url of the href
    // use this over link.attr("href") to avoid relative url
    String linkURL = link.absUrl("href");


    // display
    System.out.println(
            String.format(
                    "%s[%s]", 
                    linkText,
                    linkURL));
```

Read more about [CSS Selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

---

You could also iterate each link in the article like this:

```
    for (Element link : doc.select("article[itemprop=articleBody] a")) {
        String linkText = link.ownText();
        String linkURL = link.absUrl("href");
        System.out.println(
                String.format(
                        "%s[%s]", 
                        linkText,
                        linkURL));
    }
```

Output

```
Link Text[http://www.URL.com]
```

Comment: not sure why your first solution gave a null pointer error. However your 2nd solution works perfectly. Thank you so much.